# Error in query between to dates. Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a problem with a query in Oracle / SQL

In the query I look for the number of visits in a time range

When I set the date ranges within the same month, everything is perfect, but when I set the date ranges in different months, it doesn't work.

Example:

*Range of Dates 01/02/18 to 02/04/18, everything perfect.*

*Range of Dates 1/28/18 to 2/4/18, the global disaster.*

**What happens?**

Bellow, I give you the access to the screenshots, and this is the code:

```
SELECT
TO_CHAR("fecha", 'DD/MM/YY') as fecha, count(TO_CHAR("fecha", 'DD/MM/YY')) as visitas 
FROM VIS 
WHERE "area" = 'home' 
  AND TO_CHAR("fecha", 'DDMMYY') >= '270118' 
  AND TO_CHAR("fecha", 'DDMMYY') <= '050218' 
GROUP BY TO_CHAR("fecha", 'DD/MM/YY') 
ORDER BY TO_CHAR("fecha", 'DD/MM/YY') ASC;
```

The query works

[image: The query works]

The query doesn't work

[image: The query doesn't work]

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images, or links to images.

Comment: Screenshots taken by camera - is this a joke?

Comment: Why on earth are you converting your date column to strings then trying to use `<=`?  *(Are you aware that as a string `'060118'` comes **after** `'050218'`?)*  What data-type is `fetcha`?  Hopefully it's a native `DATETIME` or similar type, if so, why not filter using that type?  As for the screen shots, wouldn't you expect it to be easier for us to debug and test suggestions if you gave us TEXT that we could copy and paste?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try it as below.. you need to convert the hardcoded value to date format instead of converting date column to char.

```
SELECT
fecha, count(fecha) as visitas 
FROM VIS 
WHERE "area" = 'home' 
  AND fecha between to_date('012718','MM/DD/YY') and to_date('020518','MM/DD/YY') 
  GROUP BY FECHA
  ORDER BY FECHA ASC;
```

Comment: Although `to_date('020518','MM/DD/YY') ` would work you should prefer 4 digits for year ([Y2K bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem)) and format string `MM/DD/YY` should match input value.

Answer (score 0):

`XYZ >= '270118' AND XYZ <= '050218'` will never return anything because `2` is greater than `0`, thus it is not possible to have both conditions TRUE.

A value cannot be greater than 2 and at the same time lower than 0

Assuming data type of `fecha` is `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` you can simply compare date values, for example:

```
WHERE "fecha" >= DATE '2018-01-27' 
  AND "fecha" <= DATE '2018-02-05'
```

or

```
WHERE "fecha" >= TO_DATE('270118', 'DDMMRR')
  AND "fecha" <= TO_DATE('050218', 'DDMMRR')
```

`RR` is the 2-digit format for year, however you should always prefer 4 digits for year, i.e.  `TO_DATE('27012018', 'DDMMYYYY')`

If your `"fecha"` data also contain time values (i.e. time values different to `00:00:00`), you should consider to use `WHERE TRUNC("fecha") >= ...`.

You should also use DATE value for `ORDER BY "fecha"`, otherwise 31st of December 2001 will come **after** 2018-02-05 (i.e. today) - I don't think this is your intention. `ASC` is the default sort order, so you can skip it if you like.